# Global variable in python with image processing

Tags: python, class, tkinter, global

how can i make vehicle_count as a global variable so i can call it on the file class it has a use of car counting with opencv

```
class Vehicle_Counting:
    
    def __init__(self, window):
        self.window = window
        self.window.geometry('1366x768')
        self.window.resizable(0, 0)
        self.window.state('zoomed')
        self.window.title('Page2')

        self.window.config(background='yellow')

        B1 = Button(self.window, text="Count first lane", bg="dark orange", font=("Arial", 15), command=self.Counter)
        B1.place(x=450, y=20)

        B2 = Button(self.window, text="Count second lane", bg="dark orange", font=("Arial", 15), command=self.Counter2)
        B2.place(x=650, y=20)

        B2 = Button(self.window, text="Proceed to Stop Light Timer", bg="dark orange", font=("Arial", 15),
                    command=self.Countdown_Timer)
        B2.place(x=850, y=20)

    def Counter(self):
        vd = VehicleDetector()
        img = cv2.imread("images/car-6810885__340.jpg")
        vehicle_boxes = vd.detect_vehicles(img)
        vehicle_count = len(vehicle_boxes)
        for box in vehicle_boxes:
            x, y, w, h = box
            cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (25, 0, 180), 3)
            cv2.putText(img, "Vehicles:" + str(vehicle_count), (20, 50), 0, 2, (100, 200, 0), 3)

        cv2.imshow("Cars", img)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
```

i need to call the vehicle_count in this class in order to make a decision

```
class Countdown_Timer(Vehicle_Counting):
    def __init__(self, window):
        self.window = window
        self.window.geometry('1366x768')
        self.window.resizable(0, 0)
        self.window.state('zoomed')
        self.window.title('Page2')

        B1 = Button(self.window, text="Computer for the Timer", bg="dark orange", font=("Arial", 15), command=self.RG_timer)
        B1.place(x=450, y=20)

    def RG_timer(self):
        if Vehicle_Counting.vehicle_count == 0:
            messagebox.showinfo("")
```

im expecting to call it in a class on other file so i can create a if else statement.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use global variable, use instance variable of `Vehicle_Counting` and pass it to instance of `Countdown_Timer`.

Below is the modified code:

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

class Vehicle_Counting:

    def __init__(self, window):
        self.window = window
        self.window.geometry('1366x768')
        self.window.resizable(0, 0)
        #self.window.state('zoomed')
        self.window.title('Page2')

        self.window.config(background='yellow')

        B1 = Button(self.window, text="Count first lane", bg="dark orange", font=("Arial", 15), command=self.Counter)
        B1.place(x=450, y=20)

        B2 = Button(self.window, text="Count second lane", bg="dark orange", font=("Arial", 15), command=self.Counter2)
        B2.place(x=650, y=20)

        B2 = Button(self.window, text="Proceed to Stop Light Timer", bg="dark orange", font=("Arial", 15),
                    command=self.open_countdown_timer)
        B2.place(x=850, y=20)

    def Counter(self):
        '''
        vd = VehicleDetector()
        img = cv2.imread("images/car-6810885__340.jpg")
        vehicle_boxes = vd.detect_vehicles(img)
        self.vehicle_count = len(vehicle_boxes) # use instance variable instead of local variable
        for box in vehicle_boxes:
            x, y, w, h = box
            cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (25, 0, 180), 3)
        cv2.putText(img, "Vehicles:" + str(self.vehicle_count), (20, 50), 0, 2, (100, 200, 0), 3)

        cv2.imshow("Cars", img)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
        '''
        self.vehicle_count = 0  # just simulate result of OpenCV detection

    def Counter2(self):
        self.vehicle_count = 10 # just simulate result of OpenCV detection

    def open_countdown_timer(self):
        win = Toplevel(self.window)
        win.transient(self.window)
        Countdown_Timer(win, self.vehicle_count) # pass to Countdown_Timer

class Countdown_Timer:
    def __init__(self, window, vehicle_count):
        self.window = window
        self.window.geometry('1366x768')
        self.window.resizable(0, 0)
        #self.window.state('zoomed')
        self.window.title('Page2')

        self.vehicle_count = vehicle_count # save to an instance variable

        B1 = Button(self.window, text="Computer for the Timer", bg="dark orange", font=("Arial", 15), command=self.RG_timer)
        B1.place(x=450, y=20)

    def RG_timer(self):
        if self.vehicle_count == 0:
            messagebox.showinfo("Error", "No vehicle found")
        else:
            messagebox.showinfo("Info", f"Total {self.vehicle_count} vehicles found")

root = Tk()
Vehicle_Counting(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Note that I have comment out the OpenCV stuff to make the code runs without OpenCV.

Comment: i used 2 def Counter cause im calculating 2 images on the open cv i just need to learn how can i import the variable vehicle_count to the class countdown timer cause im calculating the green light and red light of a stop light on a given intersection

Comment: My example shows you how to pass `vehicle_count` to `Countdown_Timer`.  So I don't understand your comment.

Comment: like if vehicle_count == 0 && vehicle_count2 == 0
       print no traffic 
            else if vehicle_count > 20 && vehicle_count2 < 0
            print traffic is only on the side of vehicle_count

Comment: Still don't understand what you want to achieve on *"if vehicle_count = 0 && vehicle_count = 0"*.

Comment: i didnt put the other function because basically its the same i just need to call the vehicle_count so i can compute an intersection

Comment: i dont know if i need to make the vehicle_count global so i can access it on another class and the class is on another file

Comment: As I said, I have told you how to pass `vehicle_count` from `Vehicle_Counting` to `Countdown_Timer`.  It works even when the two classes are in different files.

Comment: if i make vehicle_count = 0 it only reads 0 and not the count on the image processing

Comment: I just use `vehicle_count = 0` to simulate the result of image detection as I don't have the required video and `OpenCV` module. You can use your original code related to OpenCV to set `self.vehicle_count`.

Comment: Countdown_Timer.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'vehicle_count'

Comment: Did you read and understand my example?

Comment: i didnt see this one Countdown_Timer(win, self.vehicle_count) # pass to Countdown_Timer
my bad

Comment: hello sir i have a new problem can u help me